# How to prove this limit equality? $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2^{a_n} = 2^{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n}$

Tags: limits

Could somebody tell me how one exactly could prove the following equality:

Is the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2^{a_n} = 2^{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n}$ valid for all sequences $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$

It looks pretty much the same and I would say yes...but its just intuition...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's true, since $f(x) = 2^x$ is a continuous functions.

Comment: But that's an elementary property of continuous functions....

Comment: @ParthThakkar I gave a proof IF the O.P. already knows that the exponential function is continuous (his/her question is obviously equivalent to that). If s/he needs to PROVE that the exponential function is continuous, that's a different matter.

Comment: Sorry Igor, I didn't read the question properly. Deleting the comment.